# -Distribution of sum- Monty Hall Parody

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that in a television show you've won three blank vouchers $$S_a,S_b,S_c$$ with total amount $600$ euro.
The stage has three doors $A,B,C$ which opened with keys $a,b,c$ respectively.

Behind the door $A$ stand operator who turns voucher $S_a$, into $S_a$ cash.

Behind the door $B$ stand operator who turns voucher $S_b$ into $5\cdot S_b$ ​​cash.

Behind the door $C$ stand operator who turns voucher $S_c$ into $2\cdot S_c$ ​​cash.

Moderator of the show then ask you to choose one of three keys $a,b,c$ .
The question is how we should distribute the amount acquired through vouchers for the most money, despite the choice of the key.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  If I choose key $b$, say, what do I get?  Do I get $S_a+5S_b$ or $max(S_a,5S_b)$ or what?  You say the vouchers are blank...what does that mean?  Do I know how much each is worth or not?

Comment: Also:  what am I trying to optimize?  The dollar value assuming I choose the key randomly?  The dollar value assuming I choose the key optimally?

Comment: blank mean that we can write the sum desired in each voucher but the total sum must be 600

Comment: So...I know the value of each voucher?  Then there is no probability involved here, right?  I know exactly what my payout will be for each possible action and will just choose the largest one.  Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: maximum 3000 we gain if we write 600 in $S_b$ and if we choose the key $b$ but that is not for sure if we choose another key we gain 0.

Comment: But why on earth would I choose another key?  I think there is something I am missing.  If, for example, I didn't know the value of the vouchers then I might fear that you'd deliberately make $S_b=0$.  That's why I keep asking if the contestant can see the values.  That knowledge would appear to kill the game theoretic aspect of the question.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the key is chosen randomly?  That isn't clear from the phrasing of the question, but it would at least add a probabilisitic component.  (In that case the expected payout is $\frac 13(3S_a+5S_b+2S_c)$ and this is still maximized by putting all the money onto $S_b$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum we split in the parts by proportion
$$S_a:S_b:S_c=1:1/5:1/2$$
$$S_a+S_b+S_c=600$$
$$S_a/1=S_b/(1/5)=S_c/(1/2)=k$$
$$k+k/5+k/2=600$$
$$k=6000/17=352,94$$
$$S_a=352,94,S_b=70,58,S_c=176.47$$